# Is $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\log^2 {n}}$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: convergence-divergence

Cauchy ratio test yields 1 (so it's inconclusive). I have tried this:

$$\frac{1}{n \log^2n}=\frac{1}{n \log n \log n}=\frac{1}{\log n^n \log n}\geq \frac{1}{\log n^n -n} \approx \frac{1}{\log n!} $$

Now, since $\sum 1/\log n!$ diverges, the original series must diverge too. But Wolfram Alpha says it's convergent. How did I go wrong and how can I solve this?

Comment: Try integral test. $1/n$ is the derivative of $logn$

Comment: I haven't seen that one in class, so even if it's useful (and I'm gonna learn it) there must be another way to evaluate this without using that test.

Comment: On a side note, [here's](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Boas.pdf) a paper that discusses the slow convergence of this series (and others).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find it easier to apply the [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test):

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n\log^2n}\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^n}{2^n\log^22^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2\log^22}$$

Comment: Typo? You mean $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n\log^2n}\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^n}{2^n\log^22^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2\log^22}$

Comment: @chilangoincomprendido Oh, nvm, I'm stupid :D  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: There is a typo.  The argument on the logarithm is $2$, not $n$.

Comment: This makes more sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Manuel :-) No problem

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, what went wrong was your inequality chain. We have that
$$\frac{1}{\ln \left(x^x\right)-x} \gg \frac{1}{\ln \left(x^x\right)\ln x}$$ contrary to what your inequality chain would imply.

Comment: You're right, what a silly mistake :(